# I use this autocomplete?

Tags: jquery

I use this script for autocomplete...

```
$('#custmoers_name').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {

    // $.getJSON("<?php echo base_url('index.php/Json_cr_operation/autosearch_custmoers');?>", function (data) {
      $.getJSON("Json_cr_operation/autosearch_custmoers?term=" + request.term, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
            console.log(value);
            return {
                label: value.label,
                value: value.value
            };
       }));
      });
   },
   minLength: 1,
   delay: 100
});
```

My json return :- [{"label":"Mahesh Arun Wani","value":"1"}] after search m

but it display in dropdown [object object]...

Comment: What is your real question? and why have you included your code twice?

Answer (score 0):

The data returned maybe array of objects but the data is not extracted properly. F12, Keep debugger in the map function and find how to get the value. I hope below code will work for you. Put this inside your response.

```
$.map(data, function (item, index) {
    return {
        label: item.Value,
        value: item.Key
    };
})
```

Comment: autocomplete not search any item...
I search m and i return
[{"label":"Mahesh Arun Wani","value":"1"},{"label":"Aniket Patil 11111111","value":"2"},{"label":"Nikhil Wani","value":"3"}] in jdon respons...

but on search autocomplete not suggest any item..